# How to get tensor from multiple models and average them?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor2tensor

I am trying to average tensor of two model with identical structure but trained with different datasets. The model are stored in ckpt file.

I tried to look at [avg_checkpoints function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/blob/master/tensor2tensor/utils/avg_checkpoints.py) from tensor2tensor but have no idea how to use it.

How do I solve the problem?

```
from tensor2tensor.utils import avg_checkpoints

print(avg_checkpoints.checkpoint_exists("/"))
#I got true from console
#I have copied final ckpt from different model to the root file

avg_checkpoint.main(?)
#no idea what to replace the ? with
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[avg_checkpoints.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/blob/master/tensor2tensor/utils/avg_checkpoints.py) is an executable script, so you can use it from the command line, e.g.:

```
python utils/avg_checkpoints.py
  --checkpoints path/to/checkpoint1,path/to/checkpoint2
  --num_last_checkpoints 2
  --output_path where/to/save/the/output
```

Note that if the two checkpoints were trained on different datasets from scratch, the averaging would not work. If you had a single pre-trained model which you just fine-tuned on two different datasets, then the averaging could work.

You can average more than two checkpoints. A hacky, but simple way to add weights for each checkpoint is to include it multiple times in `--checkpoints` (and increase `num_last_checkpoints` accordingly).

Comment: Thanks a lot! And you are right...average multiple model that trained from scratch doesn't work at all

Comment: For some reason when running utils/avg_checkpoints.py i get: OP_REQUIRES failed at random_op.cc:202 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[512] ... But the training went fine. How can it be? Maybe the avg_checkpoints requires much more memory than the training itself?

Comment: @NadavB: Try running the averaging on CPU (it is faster than on GPU anyway). You can also try t2t-avg-all.